# Script com Múltiplos Envios

Tags: autohotkey

Eu estou com a seguinte duvida. Estou tentando fazer um script no AHK que realize a seguinte função:

Quando pressionada a teclada do mouse (XB1), o script deveria enviar [Shift+F1], logo após manter pressionada a tecla [Z].

Quando a tecla (XB1) fosse solta, o script deveria enviar [Shift+F2] e soltar a tecla [Z].

Até essa parte eu consegui fazer sem problemas, porem o script está executando apenas uma vez, e eu precisava que eles executasse essa verificação toda vez que a tecla fosse pressionada. Vou colocar o código logo a baixo.

```
main(){
    MsgBox, "Estou na Main!"
    while GetKeyState("XButton1","P"){
        MsgBox, "Pressionado Main()"
        Send, {Z Down}
    }
    MsgBox, "Estou fora do While na Main!"
    Send, {Z Up}
    MsgBox, "Subi a Letra Z"
    Sleep, 100
    Send, +{F2 Down} +{F2 Up}
    MsgBox, "Enviei o F2"
}

XButton1:
    If GetKeyState("XButton1","P"){
        MsgBox, "Pressionado!"
        Send, +{F1 Down} +{F1 Up}
        Sleep, 100
        main()
    }else{
        MsgBox, "Não Pressionado!"
    }
Return
ESC:: ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XButton1::
  Send, +{F1}
  Send, {Z Down}
Return

XButton1 Up::
  Send, {Z Up}
  Send, +{F2}
Return

ESC:: ExitApp
```

Comment: Felipe muito obrigado, tu mostrou uma solução muito simples, pra algo que eu estava tentando complicar.